# set class='active' using current_page for index and show actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This should be working, but isn't... I want to style a nav link for both index and show actions for articles.

```
<li class="<%= "active" if current_page?(articles_path(@article))  %>"><%= link_to '/articles' do %>
                       <span>articles</span><span class="rd-navbar-label text-middle label-custom label-danger label-xs-custom label-rounded-custom label">new</span>
                      <% end %>
                      </li>
```

The Active class should apply when path is /articles OR /articles/5 but only works on /articles.

I tried `<%= "active" if current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'index') || current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'show') %>`
but that causes a No route matches `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}` when another link uses a different controller.

This should be simple... how?

Here is all the navbar code... while we're at it, how to make a link to an anchor active when url is `/#solutions`

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
                      <li class="<%= "active" if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "home", root_path %></li>

                      <li><%= link_to "Solutions", root_url(:anchor => "solutions") %></li>

                      <li class="<%= "active" if current_page?(contact_path) %>"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
                      <li class="<%= "active" if current_page?(faq_path) %>"><%= link_to "faq", faq_path %></li>

                        <li class="<%= "active" if current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'index') || current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'show') %>"><%= link_to '/articles' do %>
                       <span>articles</span><span class="rd-navbar-label text-middle label-custom label-danger label-xs-custom label-rounded-custom label">new</span>
                      <% end %>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried comparing the string to `controller.controller_name` like `controller.controller_name == 'articles'`?

```
<li class="<%= "active" if controller.controller_name == 'articles' %>"><%= link_to '/articles' do %><span>articles</span><span class="rd-navbar-label text-middle label-custom label-danger label-xs-custom label-rounded-custom label">new</span>
```

Comment: No. But that works as expected, thanks. Knew I was missing something obvious.